# Align WooCommerce Products

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I want to properly align shop page products, Where "Star Reviews" are missing. Please check the attached screenshot 
[image]

And link to the page is http://www.madaar.net/hbhmeats/shop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a container for both div "star-rating and price" and define min-height in container.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.